# Laravel 7 Search Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to build a search engine but I am coming up blank with how to build the search. I have about 5 input fields for the user to search (heading , usersGroup , course ,title(question type). I am test one code ,and its work just for search according the title,but for other search it dose not work ,what should I do??

```
 public function show_page_search()
{
    $headings = heading::all();
    $usersGroup = usersGroup::all();
    $courses = course::all();
    $questionType = $this->questionType;
    return view('Admin.Page.Question.search', compact(['headings', 'usersGroup', 'courses', 'questionType']));
}

public function get_data_search(Request $request)
{
    $questions = question::Where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->title}%")->get();
    if ($request->type !== null)
        $questions = $questions->where('type', $request->type)->all();
```

Its my Model :

```
class question extends Model{
protected $table = 'questions';
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function headings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(heading::class, 'question_headings', 'question_id', 'heading_id');
}

public function userGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(usersGroup::class, 'question_users_groups', 'question_id', 'users_groups_id');
}

public function opt()
{
    return $this->hasMany(questionOpt::class, 'question_id');
}

public function answer()
{
    return $this->hasMany(answerQuestion::class, 'question_id');
}
```

it is my view :

```
  <tbody class="text-center">
                            @forelse(session()->get('questions') as $question)
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><span
                                            class="badge badge-success p-2">{{ $loop->iteration }}</span></th>
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach($question->headings as $heading)
                                            <span>{{$heading->title}}, </span>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach($question->userGroup as $userGroup)
                                            <span>{{$userGroup->name}}, </span>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{get_question_type_name($question->type)}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$question->title}}</td>
                                    <td>
```

Comment: Get rid of `get` and `all`  and build the query first. Once you have dealt with all where conditions you call `$question->get()` at the end.

Comment: @user3532758  could you please describe it more ,or say one example??

Comment: I'll post an answer to show what I meant

Comment: so you want to apply this search to the `heading`, `usersGroup` and `course` fields as well?

Answer (score 1):

`get` and `all` returns the result as a collection. So before calling any method that would return the result, you would build the complete query.

So change this:

```
public function get_data_search(Request $request)
{
$questions = question::Where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->title}%")->get(); //remove this get()
if ($request->type !== null)
    $questions = $questions->where('type', $request->type)->all(); //remove this all()
```

To this:

```
public function get_data_search(Request $request)
{
    $questions = Question::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->title}%");
    if ($request->type !== null)
        $questions->where('type', $request->type); //use `like` if you want
    if (another condition)
        $questions->where('column', 'value');
  //and finally call get() or all() or paginate() to get the final result
  $questions->get();
  return view('view', compact('questions'));
 }
```

Comment: you know ,now I have problem in my relationship ,I added my view ,for that what could I do??

Comment: @melli I'm not sure I follow.. also it's best if you added a new question if this is a new problem, with specifics related to the new problem.

Comment: @ user3532758 oK ,tnx